# Problems with Socket.IO + Nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx, socket.io

I have developed one socket.io script with that script i want to achieve thousands of users concurrency. so, i tried following tutorial.
http://jakubracek.net/2013/07/30/scaling-socketio-horizontally-using-redis-behind-nginx/

here on my system i have created multiple nodejs+socket.io servers that are running on following ports 5656,5657,5658.
the problem i am facing is when i have only one nodejs server is running it works fine and it goes up to 10k+ users concurrency. but if i will run the same with multiple servers with different port it keeps rejecting connection requests. here i have tried reverse proxy nginx. which balances the load by distributing my connection requests to each nodejs servers.

my nginx configurations are :

`upstream backend {
        least_conn;
        server 127.0.0.1:5656;
        server 127.0.0.1:5657;
        server 127.0.0.1:5658;
    }`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name $hostname;
    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://backend;
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

i want a solution. how can i achieve thousands of users concurrency.

Comment: Have you tried increasing worker_processes or worker_connections? In the case of reverse proxy, max clients = worker_processes * worker_connections/4

Comment: Do you have a huge push on CPU or Memory after you distribute to multiple server? I remembered that RedisStore has lots of problem with CPU overload because its poor structure. I don't know if this has been fixed yet or not but I guess it's not since the creator currently focus on 1.0.